# Replacing semicolon for comma in csv using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working with a `.csv` file and, as always, it has format problems. In this case it's a `;` separated table, but there's a row that sometimes has semicolons, like this:

```
code;summary;sector;sub_sector
1;fishes;2;2
2;agriculture; also fishes;1;2
3;fishing. Extraction;  animals;2;2
```

So there are three cases:

- no semicolon -> no problem
- word character(non-numeric), semicolon, whitespace, word character(non-numeric)
- word character(non-numeric), semicolon, 2xwhitespace, word character(non-numeric)

I turned the `.csv` into a `.txt` and then imported it as a string and then I compiled this regex:

```
re.compile('([^\d\W]);\s+([^\d\W])', re.S)
```

Which should do. I almost managed to replace those semicolons for commas, doing the following:

```
def replace_comma(match):
    text = match.group()
    return text.replace(';', ',')

regex = re.compile('([^\d\W]);\s+([^\d\W])', re.S)

string2 = string.split('\n')

for n,i in enumerate(string2):
    if len(re.findall('([^\d\W]);(\s+)([^\d\W])', i))>=1:
        string2[n] = regex.sub(replace_comma, i)
```

This mostly works, but when there's two whitespaces after the semicolon, it leaves an `\xa0` after the comma. I have two problems with this approach:

- It's not very straightforward
- Why is it leaving this `\xa0` character ?

Do you know any better way to approach this?

Thanks

Edit: My desired output would be:

```
code;summary;sector;sub_sector
1;fishes;2;2
2;agriculture, also fishes;1;2
3;fishing. Extraction,  animals;2;2
```

Edit: Added explanation about turning the file into a string for better manipulation.

Comment: Is there just one specific "column" where the undesirable semicolons appear (i.e. column 2 in your example)? Or, can this issue occur in different "columns" for each row?

Comment: Just one column (the second one). I should add column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I wouldn't use `regex`, `split()` and `rsplit()` with `maxpslit=` parameter is enough:

```
data = '''1;fishes;2;2
2;agriculture; also fishes;1;2
3;fishing. Extraction;  animals;2;2'''

for line in data.splitlines():
    row = line.split(';', maxsplit=1)
    row = row[:1] + row[-1].rsplit(';', maxsplit=2)
    row[1] = row[1].replace(';', ',')
    print(';'.join(row))
```

Prints:

```
1;fishes;2;2
2;agriculture, also fishes;1;2
3;fishing. Extraction,  animals;2;2
```